# onlocationChanged is called even if I am sitting at the same place

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I have used the code below and everything is working fine except that onLocationChanged is called even if I am sitting at the same location .

I thought it should be called only when I am moving right ?

**I only want to get the location after I have moved a certain distance.**

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    locationMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
    this);


}

    @Override
       public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
           Toast.makeText(this, "Working!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (location != null) {
                            double lat = location.getLatitude();
                            double lng = location.getLongitude();

                            String Text = "Latitud = " + lat + "\nLongitud = " +
     lng;

      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),Text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
           }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're requesting location updates at the shortest possible intervals/distances

```
locationMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
this);
```

This is what the documentation says about those parameters

> " The location update interval can be controlled using the minTime parameter. The elapsed time between location updates will never be less than minTime, although it can be more depending on the Location Provider implementation and the update interval requested by other applications. "
>
> The minDistance parameter can also be used to control the frequency of location updates. If it is greater than 0 then the location provider will only send your application an update when the location has changed by at least minDistance meters, AND at least minTime milliseconds have passed. However it is more difficult for location providers to save power using the minDistance parameter, so minTime should be the primary tool to conserving battery life.

I personally use a minTime of 10 seconds and 10 meters for my app

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000,
                10, locationListener);
```

Comment: Thanks Jade.Its a great answer. I have an add-on query : I would like to take updates after the location is changed as I am already taking the current location when I login to my app.How Do I disable for the first time .I mean using the code which I have typed above What should I modify ? Thanks again.Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: No problem man :)! I'm not sure on your question, sorry. After you acquire the location for the first time(when app starts), you want to then be able to get updates once the location is changed. Gotcha. You already have the code for that. What do you mean by "how do I disable for the first time"?

Comment: Does the onLocationchanged() run for the first time in the sense that ,will it run when the app starts or only after the location other than my current location has changed ?

Comment: Because when I login as I stated before, the location is updated. I would like to record location then on.

Comment: Yes, assuming that you're acquiring the current location before setting your locationListener and requesting updates..then yes, it will only update after the initial fixed location has changed

Comment: Oh Great .I will test it then will revert if any changes occur.Thanks Jade again.Have a Great Day.

Comment: I suppose, we also can use Accelerometer in order to exclude positions if we don't move,don't we?

Comment: @JadeByfield I am using Fusion Location Provider for location Updates and onlocationchanged is called even if the device is stationary. This is the code i have used.

mlocationrequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
  mlocationrequest.setInterval(60000); 
  mlocationrequest.setFastestInterval(10000);
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
    mGoogleApiClient, mlocationrequest, this);

Answer (score 5):

Network location is not as precise as you would think it is. Therefore the result returned by the sensors can fluctuate. This is even more true when you consider that GPS signal weakens if you don't have direct line of sight with the satellites, and the number of visible satellites also has effect on the precision. This gets even worse when you start using the network provider, where the position is calculated by triangulation of the signal strength of cell towers, and the number and SSIDs of visible wireless network. Since these can fluctuate quite a lot, the precision suffers greatly. There are bunch of averaging algorithms, and heuristics employed to minimize such fluctuations, but ultimately nothing can stabilize it to be as good as you expect it to be.

A simple averaging and variation filtering can help you. Adding a correction based on the device accelerometer can also help a lot, but it will make your code more complex.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your response.That is a great explanation.Sure will look into algorithm.